# PHP file upload matched pairs

Tags: php, file-upload

I am uploading a series of paired "before" and "after" images to a PHP script. When processing the uploads I have to be sure that the right 'before' and 'after' images are matched.

If I just do this :

```
before: <input type="file" name="image[]">  after: <input type="file" name="image[]">
before: <input type="file" name="image[]">  after: <input type="file" name="image[]">
```

and then just loop through the image[] array, can I rely on PHP maintaining the correct order?

The same question applies I think if I changed it to this:

```
before: <input type="file" name="before[]">  after: <input type="file" name="after[]">
before: <input type="file" name="before[]">  after: <input type="file" name="after[]">
```

There, I still need to be sure that the before[] array and the after[] array will be in order, plus now I have to coordinate the two in any loop.

ALternatively I could do

```
before: <input type="file" name="before1">  after: <input type="file" name="after1">
before: <input type="file" name="before2">  after: <input type="file" name="after2">
etc....
```

(probably what I would do in .net) but i am not quite sure how I would loop through that in PHP.

So, can I count on PHP maintaining the input order when building the $_FILES array or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force array keys within the php-array extension, e.g.

```
name="before[1]"     name="after[1]"
name="before[2]"     name="after[2]"
```

and PHP will create array entries using those keys when it's processing the form data

Alternatively, you could simply have something like

```
foreach(array_keys($_FILES['before']['tmp_name'])) as $key) {
    processFile($_FILES['before']['tmp_name'][$key]);
    processFile($_FILES['after']['tmp_name'][$key]);
}
```

note that PHP has a moronic way of handling array-based file uploads, and having to loop on the `['tmp_name']` attribute (or any other attribute in the $_FILES array) is necessary.

For your `before1`, `before2`,etc... version, you can also do something like

```
$keys = preg_grep('/^after\d+$/', array_keys($_FILES['before']['tmp_name']));
```

which'll give you array:

```
 $keys = array(
    0 => 'after1',
    1 => 'after2', 
    ...
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the name field to create an array as you have shown in your example, PHP will provide an array in the same order as they are submitted in the form.  Beware, you are essentially trusting user input for this.  That is, if ANYTHING (e.g. a maliciously created form or a XSS injection) were to alter your form and post that instead then your data order could change.  This is the same risk as with any other kind of form manipulation.  So, PHP shouldn't muck with it, but the golden rule is not to trust user input.